# Electrons in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, atomic-physics

There is a question which is "A beam of electrons enters a uniform magnetic field of $1.2 \  \text{T}$. What is the energy difference between the electrons parallel and anti-parallel to the field."

My question is how can the electron beam be parallel and anti-parallel at the same time?

Comment: I think they are asking you two assume two independent cases, not the same electron.

Comment: Parallel and antiparallel  might mean the direction of the *spin* of the electrons, and hence is a problem about the spin magnetic moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $F_{b} = q (\vec{v} × \vec{B})$

There is a force perpendicular to the velocity. This force is going to want to cause a form of circular motion, changing the initial velocity, perpendicular to its original value at some time t.

As a result of this force, we need to find the work done between the particles entering, and exiting perpendicular.

W = $\int \vec{F}_{b} \cdot \vec{dr} = q (\vec{v} × \vec{B}) \cdot dr$

$ = q (\vec{v} × \vec{B}) \cdot \vec{v} dt$

= 0 as a vector perpendicular to v, dotted with v is zero

So no work is done, so they have the same kinetic  energy